# C++ Redistributable 2012 update 3 detection

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to detect if C++ Redistributable 2012 update 3 is installed on machine.... I am currently doing check for 2008 through registry search and using guid, but I do not know guid for 2012 update 3... Does anybody know how to detect it?

I also found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed) but it`s not exactly for update 3 and I do not know right numbers which I should to check...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can figure this out yourself for *any* installer: use a pc that doesn't yet have the product installed, start [procomon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), add a filter so that includes only info from the installer process (something like `command line contains vcRedist` should be sufficient) and start the installer. After it finishes, examine which registry keys it wrote.

For VS2102 the interesting stuff will be here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\11.0
```

(which is by the way also answered in the question you link to)

**edit** in addition to the above, you could also check

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\5C4834679ACBC703A9CADF44632686A6
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{764384C5-BCA9-307C-9AAC-FD443662686A}
```

(note both are for the x64 redistributable), that's how eg Installshield's prerequisites perform the check.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct answer? I need to check if it is  UPDATE 3 version... what if is installed just basic 2012 redist?

Comment: Read carefully: the first paragraph can't possibly be wrong. Did you try it? As for the second paragraph: did you compare the contents of that registry key before and after installing update 3? You should see it will have different version numbers.

Comment: well I checked the numbers... they did not change... I am checking the registry way with guid right now...

Comment: you're doing something wrong then.. pre-update 3 has version number 11.0.50727, update 3 is 11.0.60610

Comment: Ok it was caused because I had installed also VS 2012... I accept solution with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\11.0
after some test it looks like it is what I was looking for... Just do not forget that in Version you found the newest one... so if somebody want to check then condition should be 11.0.60610 or greater...

Comment: On my computer, there are three subkeys under 11.0: `RuntimeAdditional`, `RuntimeDebug`, and `RuntimeMinimum`. The version numbers were found under these subkeys, but not found on the `11.0` key.