# Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 check is not being detected correctly

Tags: c#, .net, registry, regedit

I have a custom application that needs to check if `Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable` is installed in my machine.

I googled, and I found that the physical path in the Windows Registry (that you can search using Regedit) are the following:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\Runtimes\x86
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\Runtimes\x86
```

You can see these links in [this Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14878248/760893).

But for some reasons, my application doesn't find it sometimes. In this cases, I'm using two different Admin accounts for installing them, but I think it makes no difference.

I also found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398867/760893) other locations to look. But I'm not using them. 
Here's my code:

```
....
 bool vc2012Installed = CheckVisualRedistributable(vc2012RedistRoutes);
....

private bool CheckVisualRedistributable(string[] redistCheck)
{
    try
    {
        int installed = -1;
        foreach (string route in redistCheck)
        {
            RegistryKey vcRedistKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(route);
            if (vcRedistKey == null) { continue; }

            installed = (int)vcRedistKey.GetValue("Installed");
            if (installed == 1) break;
        }
        if (installed == -1) return false;

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CheckVisualRedistributable: " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I don't know why in some cases the `C++ Redistributable 2012` is not being detected...

Any idea on what might be wrong? Maybe a user account problem?

NOTE: Problems appear on Windows 8.1. Works fine on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you checked that the appropriate key is there in the registry on the machines where the application is not finding it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually, if you try to reinstall the Visual C++ again, it says "Repair, uninstall", so it's present!

Comment: What im trying to get at is your registry check a reliable way to see if it is installed or is it possible that your check fails because the keys you are checking are not set as you expect them to be even though it is installed

Comment: You mean that the flag is possible that is not installed in the places I mention?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i mean.

Comment: Maybe that's the information I need, but since now the only thing I get is the info listed above. Do you have some more information on where can it be located?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the `Installed` value of

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\[WOW6432Node]\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{VCRedist_GUID}` key

- where GUID of `VC++ 2012 (x86)` is `{33d1fd90-4274-48a1-9bc1-97e33d9c2d6f}`
- `WOW6432Node` will be present or not depending on the `VC++ redist` product