# Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 Installer displaying in Chinese

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, redistributable, visual-c++-runtime

I need to install [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) but when I run it, it opens in Chinese even though I selected English. I have tried in three different browsers. When I right click the downloaded file from Microsoft, it says English in the details.

I am not familiar with Microsoft support, and I couldn't find any place to report anything. I am afraid to install it and do any damage. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I also see Chinese text as opposed to the anticipated English. Looks like someone messed up -- hopefully it gets fixed soon.

Comment: [Relevant Microsoft Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808734/visual-c-redistributable-2012-update-4-installs-in-chinese-language-instead-of-english)

Comment: Voting to re-open. Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on topic as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Haha can't believe this is off topic.

Comment: @aknewhope it's been reopened, finally

Comment: @Laurent - you will find the direct download here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a problem on Microsoft side, that [has been](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808734/visual-c-redistributable-2012-update-4-installs-in-chinese-language-instead-of-english) [reported](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_update/visual-studio-2012-redistributable-dialog-shows/3ee502ee-bf58-488a-83a5-3762f36d71df), and a fix should be available sooner or later.

Meanwhile, if you have installed the [complete Visual Studio 2012 update 4](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update), the redistributable msi that were installed locally are free from this problem, find them in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\redist\1033`.

I've put the correct msi (links deleted).

**EDIT**

[The official link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) is now fixed, download is correct.

Comment: For me installation from the folder Visual Studio 11.0\VC\redist\1033 didn't help, instead I copied files from '\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC110.DebugCRT'

Comment: It is a 404 error ... I cannot find that Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 anywhere ...

Comment: Now you should be able to download it from https://my.visualstudio.com/downloads . You should have visual studio subscriptions for this