# How To Detect Visual C++ 2012 X64 RunTime In Wix Bootstrapper Project

Tags: wix, wix3.7, wix3.8

I want to detect If Visual C++ 2012 X64 RunTime  is installed or not.

There is samples and Registery keys sample for Visual C++ 2010 But I can not figure out for C++ 2012 X64 RunTime  registery  search key .

So How To Detect Visual C++ 2012 X64 RunTime In Wix Bootstrapper Project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed)

Comment: Not duplicate... I look for Wix solution ,  easy way to do ...