# What VC++ redistributable comes with Windows 8.x (if any)?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I am puzzled what results I am getting with Windows 8.1 Enterprise (64-bit). I am looking for 32-bit version of VC++ 2012 redist and following the answers from: [Detect if Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed) I found out that

- VC++ 2012 is not on programs list (Control Panel / Programs AKA Uninstall Software)
- there is no `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VC\Servicing\11.0\Runt‌​imeMinimum`
- yet there is library "%windir%\SysWOW64\msvcr110.dl"

For now I am lost what I am looking at, so my question is -- with what stuff Windows 8.x is shipping?

*Vote for close? Please tell why, thank you.*

Comment: It's possible that it doesn't ship with the redistributable, and the presence of one of the DLL files from that redist is a coincidence.

Comment: since windows 8 (and its flavours) come with .NET framework 4.5 so I am sure you should use Visual C++ Redistributes for VS 2012

Comment: @AliKazmi, I don't understand what you are saying -- I am not asking what lib I should use (I already use it), but if Win 8.x has it.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, I rephrase then -- is installing VC++2012 is required for Win 8.x or all components are in place? I can test it on this or that computer but it does not make the rule.

Comment: The first two points in your question would imply that you should install whichever redist you need. The third point is probably a coincidence.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/04/11/10516280.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft ships **msvcrt.dll** along with Windows, You must distribute all other dlls.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kche8ah(v=vs.110).aspx

I agree with @Roger Lipscombe, The third point is probably a coincidence.