# Add prerequisites to visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, prerequisites

I want to add new prerequisites to visual studio 2015 but can not find out the solution:
[image]

As you can see, the visual studio 2015 lack of Prerequisites Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Library (x86) and Windows Installer 3.1. I'm using windows 8.1 so i can not install the old version of Visual C++ Runtime Library (x86) and Windows Installer.

Answer (score 7):

I've run in the same problem. You should follow the steps for adding `Bootstrapper packages` into your `Visual Studio 2015` folder.

I'll explain the step used by me to add `Microsoft C++ 2013 x86` (the steps in your case would be similar).

First navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\` folder (for previous versions of `Visual Studio` or custom paths this can be different).

Once located the `Packages` folder you can start by creating a new folder called `vc_redist_2013_x86` (in your case `vc_redist_2010_x86`). 
Download the Redistribution package from Microsoft site and place it in this folder. You can download the 2013 version from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) and 2010 x86 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555).

Now copy the files from the `vcredist_x86` to your folder (it should be a product.xml file and a en folder with a package.xml file). Now remove them the read-only flag and open in any text editor.

In case of the `product.xml` you should replace the following:

- ProductCode to: "Microsoft.Visual.C++.12.0.x86" (you will have C++.10.0.x86)
- PackageFile Name="vcredist_x86.exe" will be named as the executable file that you've downloaded from Microsoft site.
- PublicKey needs to be changed according to the one of the exe file. In order to find it you have to do the following steps:

  - right click the exe-file (in my case vcredist.exe)
  - choose 'properties'
  - select 'digital-signatures'
  - select the top signature (sha1)
  - press 'Details'
  - press 'View Certificate'
  - select 'Details tab'
  - select 'Public Key'
  - copy value from below and after removing spaces you have the searched value
- MsiProductCheck Product needs to be changed to the one for your version. I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34209692/1787796) answer with the desired value. For 2013 x86 your Product is `{f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1}` and for 2010 x86 is `{1D5E3C0FEDA1E123187686FED06E995A}`.

Save file and move to the `package.xml` file. Here you have to replace the 'Visual C++ "14"' to your used version. I replaced it with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86)'.

Once this steps done. You should be able to see the `Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86)` under the Prerequisites list in your `Visual Studio 2015`.

I'll post the two files below in case you need a model on which to work on.

**Product.xml**

```
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="Microsoft.Visual.C++.12.0.x86">

  <!-- Defines list of files to be copied on build -->
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
    <PackageFile Name="vcredist_x86.exe" HomeSite="VCRedistExe" PublicKey="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" />
  </PackageFiles>

  <InstallChecks>
    <MsiProductCheck Property="VCRedistInstalled" Product="{f65db027-aff3-4070-886a-0d87064aabb1}"/>
  </InstallChecks>

  <!-- Defines how to invoke the setup for the Visual C++ 14.0 redist -->
  <Commands Reboot="Defer">
    <Command PackageFile="vcredist_x86.exe" Arguments=' /q:a '>

      <!-- These checks determine whether the package is to be installed -->
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VCRedistInstalled" Compare="ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="3"/>
        <!-- Block install if user does not have admin privileges -->
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
        <!-- Block install on Win95 -->
        <FailIf Property="Version9X" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="4.10" String="InvalidPlatformWin9x"/>
        <!-- Block install on Vista or below -->
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="6.00" String="InvalidPlatformWinNT"/>
      </InstallConditions>

      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>

    </Command>
  </Commands>
</Product>
```

**Package.xml**

```
<Package
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
    Name="DisplayName"
    Culture="Culture"
    >

    <!-- Defines a localizable string table for error messages-->
    <Strings>
        <String Name="DisplayName">Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86)</String>
        <String Name="Culture">en</String>
        <String Name="AdminRequired">You do not have the permissions required to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86). Please contact your administrator.</String>
        <String Name="InvalidPlatformWin9x">Installation of Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86) is not supported on Windows 95. Contact your application vendor.</String>
        <String Name="InvalidPlatformWinNT">Installation of Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86) is not supported on Windows NT 4.0. Contact your application vendor.</String>
        <String Name="GeneralFailure">A failure occurred attempting to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86).</String>
        <String Name="VCRedistExe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=800028&amp;clcid=0x409</String>
    </Strings>

</Package>
```

Hope it helps and it is easy to follow this long process.