# How to add custom Prerequisites in dialogue while creating setup using VS2017 setup project?

Tags: windows-installer

I am creating a setup for windows application using VS2017. My requirement is that I need to add some prerequisites (custom) not in prerequisites dialogue. I have tried copying setup files at location
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages" but with no luck. Some threads also suggested to copy and paste at following location 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK" in bootstrapper\Packge. Some other suggested for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A" location but there is no bootstrapper folder. Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Note: My requirement is not to use ClickOnce.

Comment: If it is an option to use a commercial tools, then [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com) and [Installshield](https://www.flexerasoftware.com/install/products/installshield.html) offer good features for this. [Tools overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) - (and an [older version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50348142/129130)). Beyond your problem scenario, there are a number of [serious limitations for VS Installer Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893).

Comment: Open Source and free [WiX toolset](https://www.wixtoolset.org) also has a feature called Burn which allows you to create a `setup.exe` bootstrapper / downloader / launcher binary. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446750/removing-default-dialogs-from-msi) for two answers on Burn and commercial alternatives respectively. And [a great gateway to learn about Advanced Installer features](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29130).

Comment: Found this too: [Add prerequisites to visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41716816/129130) (not tested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. Posting answer over here for future reference. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages" I have to put "netframework4.6.1.hotfix" and "vcruntime13x64" folders having offline installers in it.The most important step i was missing i didn't paste product.xml in this folder alongwith en ( Folder) containing package.xml Once I pasted them i started showing in prerequisites dialogue window.