# How do you know where the direct download links for MSU files are?

Tags: installation, windows-update

I need to know the direct download url for KB 2670838 for my installer. I could ask for the question of "where is it?" but rather I would like to know "how are people finding it?"

There are questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed) or [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1DZBHA_lqFwJ:answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/download-kb3035583-without-using-windows-update/a9fded97-a62a-4f24-9168-3cac1b30a878%20&cd=3&hl=ja&ct=clnk&gl=us) where people know exactly where the download links are rather than support.microsoft.com redirect urls.

May I ask for your wisdom?

Answer (score 1):

For updates that would be installed with the Windows Update mechanism, you  can write code to check for a specific update and install it, as here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387101(v=vs.85).aspx

Runtimes like the C++ runtimes are often distributed with install packages and installed as prerequisites. IMO it's a waste of time (and unreliable) to try to find out if a specific version is installed - just run the redistributable exe for the one you need and it will do the right checks and install if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Phil. The reason I need specific url is because I am creating a installer and sometimes would like to install both x64 and x86 version of the redistributor without bothering any clicks from the installing user. I would like to just get the redistributable exe and call it good but since Microsoft does not supply command line argument that lets me install both of those I have to resolve my concern by getting the actual individual exe.