# WIX check if VS2015 C++ redistributable is installed

Tags: wix, vcredist

Does anybody know how to check in a WIX project, if the actuall C++ redistributable package is installed or not? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed) describes the serveral product IDs, but there is a problem with them. They change with every update of a C++ redist package. Based on that I've to apapt my checks in the WIX project every time a new VC redist package update is released, which is not a useable solution.

I want to use the `RegistrySearch` WIX element to solve this problem. Therefore I need to know a registry key that doesn't change if a newer version of a C++ redist package is installed. I've also checked the registry key described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed), but no one seems to be reliable.

Comment: Another approach is to always start it and let it decide what to do. (This option is less attractive if you would to have a bootstrapper avoid downloading it if it doesn't need to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013/2015 will add additional registry keys:

```
Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\classes\installer\Dependencies


Name                           Property
----                           --------
Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditio Version     : 12.0.21005
nalVSU_amd64,v12               (default)   : {929FBD26-9020-399B-9A7A-751D61F0B942}
                               DisplayName : Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Additional Runtime - 12.0.21005
Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditio Version     : 14.0.23026
nalVSU_amd64,v14               (default)   : {BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}
                               DisplayName : Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Additional Runtime - 14.0.23026
```

They also include keys like `Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v12`. These keys will point to the currently installed redist packages, and will be removed/added when you install a redist package.