# Visual C++ Redistributable download specific version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wix, redistributable, vcredist

Following problem: I'm implementing a WIX installer project checking if the C++ VS2015 (x86) redist package is installed. I've found this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed) describing the different registry keys for different Visual Studio versions. Actually we're using "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.23026". These package can be found under following registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}
```

This [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed) states following registry entry for the redist package:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.24215
>   Registry Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies{e2803110-78b3-4664-a479-3611a381656a}
>   Configuration: x86
>   Version: 14.0.24215.1

As can be seen the GUIDs are different.

Question: Does somebody know where I can download a specific version of a redist package? Via Google I only found links pointing to the most actual redist package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you can avoid the whole GUIDs mess using the following registry key path:

'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86' and read the 'Version' key.

About the download part - I did not find a good solution to download the x86 version.

In theory you could get the latest version link by extraction it from the **source** of the following page 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145' (Simply linking\downloading it will download the 64 bit version on 64 bit machine and will not allow the 64 or 86 choice)

Comment: I don't want the latest version of the redist package, I want a specific one.

Comment: Did you find a way to use a specific version ?