# How to get the correct return value/status of VC++ 2005 in NSIS

Tags: visual-c++, nsis, visual-c++-2005

I want to silently install [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) with NSIS.

However, the correct exit code is not being returned. I tested with several types of variations. The best I came up with is:

```
DetailPrint "Installing VC++ 2005"
    File "${STOCKINPUTFOLDER}\bin\Debug\vcredist_x86.EXE"
    ClearErrors
    ExecWait "$OUTDIR\vcredist_x86.EXE /q:a /c:$\"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qb /norestart$\"" $0 ; also can use /qn 

    ;do not delete the file out-rightly so that evaluation of IfErrors below is clean           
    IfErrors execError noError

    execError:
        Goto ShortEndInstall

    ShortEndInstall:
        MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "ShortEndInstall"
        Delete "$OUTDIR\vcredist_x86.EXE" ;we did not delete the file outrightly so that evaluation of IfErrors is clean
        Quit

    noError:
        ${If} $0 != 0
            MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "You did not complete the installation of the VC++ 2005 re-distributable. Installation will now abort. Return code $0"
            Goto ShortEndInstall
        ${EndIf}

        MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "No error"
        Delete "$OUTDIR\vcredist_x86.EXE" ;we did not delete the file outrightly so that evaluation of IfErrors is clean
```

But when I intentionally clicked on the "Cancel" button of the VC++2005 installation, NSIS still took it as being successful installation (I got the dialog box at instruction `MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "No error"`)

How can I accurately and correctly get the returned error (e.g. when I "Cancel"ed the installation myself)?

**EDIT:**

Following the help by @Anders I now have the following, which still fails (i.e. `not installed` even while the VC++ 2005 installation was completed. I also tried different command line options for the installation VC++2005)

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WordFunc.nsh

!define VERSION "8.1.0.0"
!define SHORTVERSION "8.1"
!define NAME "SchoolServer MainHost"
!define SHARPDEVFOLDER "..\..\..\.."
!define STOCKINPUTFOLDER "${SHARPDEVFOLDER}\SchoolServer_100\SS-Server"
!define PARENTSTOCKFOLDER "${SHARPDEVFOLDER}\SchoolServer_100"

!define MSVC2005_X86REDIST_PRODUCTCODE {A49F249F-0C91-497F-86DF-B2585E8E76B7}
!define MSVC2005_X86REDIST_PRODUCTCODE_SP1 {7299052B-02A4-4627-81F2-1818DA5D550D}
!define MSVC2005_X86REDIST_PRODUCTCODE_SP1_UP {837B34E3-7C30-493C-8F6A-2B0F04E2912C}
!define INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT 5

!define MACRO_check_successful_install "!insertmacro check_vc_install"
!define MACRO_check_successful_install_exclusive_2005 "!insertmacro check_vc_install_exclusive_2005"

Var function_call_return
Var tested_vc_key

!macro check_vc_install install_key
  DetailPrint "Copying  ${install_key} to tested_vc_key"
  StrCpy $tested_vc_key ${install_key}
  call check_vc_install_normal
!macroend

!macro check_vc_install_exclusive_2005 install_key
  StrCpy $tested_vc_key ${install_key}
  call check_vc_install_exclusive_2005
!macroend

OutFile "${NAME} Lite Installer - ${SHORTVERSION}.exe"

#Sections
Section "Installation"
    SetShellVarContext all
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
    SetRebootFlag false
    DetailPrint "Installing VC++ 2005"
    File "${STOCKINPUTFOLDER}\bin\Debug\vcredist_x86.EXE"
    ClearErrors
    ExecWait "$OUTDIR\vcredist_x86.EXE /q:a /c:$\"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qb /norestart$\" " $0 ; also can use /qn 

    ;we will not delete the file out-rightly so that evaluation of IfErrors below is clean      
    IfErrors execError noError

    execError:
        MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "First line error!"
        Goto ShortEndInstall

    ShortEndInstall:
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Installation of Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 runtime libraries failed!"
    Delete "$OUTDIR\vcredist_x86.EXE" ;we did not delete the file outrightly so that evaluation of IfErrors is clean
    ;Quit
    Return

    noError:
    ;if no error, then check the exit code (https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/mailman/message/22965694/ [use timemachine if 404 error. Page was accessed June 26, 2017])
    ${If} $0 != 0
        MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "You did not complete the installation of the VC++ 2005 re-distributable. Installation will now abort. [Error $0]"
        Goto ShortEndInstall
    ${EndIf}

    ClearErrors
    ${MACRO_check_successful_install} ${MSVC2005_X86REDIST_PRODUCTCODE}
    ${If} $function_call_return == "installed"
        Goto ContinueInstallation
    ${Else}
        ${MACRO_check_successful_install} ${MSVC2005_X86REDIST_PRODUCTCODE_SP1}
        ${If} $function_call_return == "installed"
            Goto ContinueInstallation
        ${Else}
            ${MACRO_check_successful_install} ${MSVC2005_X86REDIST_PRODUCTCODE_SP1_UP}
            ${If} $function_call_return == "installed"
                Goto ContinueInstallation
            ${Else}
                ${MACRO_check_successful_install_exclusive_2005} ${MSVC2005_X86REDIST_PRODUCTCODE}
                ${If} $function_call_return == "installed"
                    Goto ContinueInstallation
                ${Else}
                    ${MACRO_check_successful_install_exclusive_2005} ${MSVC2005_X86REDIST_PRODUCTCODE_SP1}
                    ${If} $function_call_return == "installed"
                        Goto ContinueInstallation
                    ${Else}
                        ${MACRO_check_successful_install_exclusive_2005} ${MSVC2005_X86REDIST_PRODUCTCODE_SP1_UP}
                        ${If} $function_call_return == "installed"
                            Goto ContinueInstallation
                        ${Else}
                            DetailPrint "Quiting... [Returned value: $function_call_return]"
                            Goto ShortEndInstall
                        ${EndIf}
                    ${EndIf}
                ${EndIf}
            ${EndIf}
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}

    ContinueInstallation:

    Delete "$OUTDIR\vcredist_x86.EXE" ;we did not delete the file outrightly so that evaluation of IfErrors is clean

    CreateDirectory  "$INSTDIR\idcard"
    File /r "${STOCKINPUTFOLDER}\bin\Debug\idcard" 
SectionEnd


Function check_vc_install_normal
    DetailPrint "check_vc_install_normal: Checking installation of $tested_vc_key"
    System::Call 'MSI::MsiGetProductInfo(t "$tested_vc_key", t "ProductName", t"?"r1, *i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})i.r0'
    ClearErrors
    ${If} $0 == 0
        DetailPrint "ProductName: $1"
        System::Call 'MSI::MsiGetProductInfo(t "$tested_vc_key", t "AssignmentType", t"?"r1, *i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})i.r0'
        DetailPrint "AssignmentType: $1"
        System::Call 'MSI::MsiGetProductInfo(t "$tested_vc_key", t "PackageCode", t"?"r1, *i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})i.r0'
        DetailPrint "PackageCode: $1"
        System::Call 'MSI::MsiGetProductInfo(t "$tested_vc_key", t "VersionString", t"?"r1, *i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})i.r0'
        DetailPrint "VersionString: $1"
        StrCpy $function_call_return "installed"
    ${Else}
        DetailPrint "Not installed [$0] [from check_vc_install_normal]"
        StrCpy $function_call_return "not installed"
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function check_vc_install_exclusive_2005
    DetailPrint "check_vc_install_exclusive_2005: Checking special vc2005 installation of $tested_vc_key"
    ClearErrors
    System::Call 'MSI::MsiQueryProductState(t "$tested_vc_key")i.r0'
    ${If} ${INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT} = $0
        StrCpy $function_call_return "installed"
    ${Else}
        DetailPrint "Not installed [$0] [from check_vc_install_exclusive_2005]"
        StrCpy $function_call_return "not installed"
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: What is $0 after ExecWait? 0 or some other number?

Comment: @Anders Always `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps vcredist_x86.exe is not returning the exit code correctly from MsiExec?

If `ExecWait` is able to find and start the process (`IfErrors` is "false") then NSIS is guaranteed to return the correct exit code from the child process.

`$0 != 0` is actually a string comparison and you should be using `$0 <> 0` to compare 32-bit numbers but it is not the problem in this case.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section

ExecWait '"cmd" /c exit 0' $0
${If} ${Errors}
${OrIf} $0 <> 0
    Abort "Error, child process exited with $0" # Will not abort here
${EndIf}

ExecWait '"cmd" /c exit 1234' $0
${If} ${Errors}
${OrIf} $0 <> 0
    Abort "Error, child process exited with $0" # Will abort here
${EndIf}

SectionEnd
```

Comment: So how do I ensure that `vcredist_x86.exe` returns the exit code correctly from `MsiExec`? (I have heard of %ERRORLEVEL% but don't know how to correctly apply its usage here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/02/07/update-regarding-silent-install-of-the-vc-8-0-runtime-vcredist-packages/?replytocom=9663#respond)

Comment: Note: running `vcredist_x86.EXE /q:a /c:"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qb /norestart"` directly from the command line and checking `%ERRORLEVEL%` even after cancelling the installation still returns `0`

Comment: Worst case scenario, check if it is installed after executing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44267754/3501 but you should try to find some command line options documentation first...

Comment: Thanks @Anders for the link you shared above. So does that means I can simply do  `System::Call 'MSI::MsiQueryProductState(t "${MSVCREDIST_PRODUCTCODE}")i.r0'` after the silent install to know if install was successful or not?

Comment: And I also believe the command line options are correct, according to http://asawicki.info/news_1597_installing_visual_c_redistributable_package_from_command_line.html

Comment: Yes MsiQueryProductState with the correct GUID should be enough. Remember to test against the correct value in $0, not just 0.

Comment: Now I always get return code `-1` (I even tried just `ExecWait "$OUTDIR\vcredist_x86.EXE /q " $0`). Meanwhile normal running of the  vcredist_x86.EXE executable from Windows Explorer installed normally and successfully

Comment: I checked with `System::Call 'MSI::MsiGetProductInfo(t "${MSVCREDIST_PRODUCTCODE}", t "ProductName", t"?"r1, *i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})i.r0'` and when that failed (i.e. in the `${Else}`) I now checked with `System::Call 'MSI::MsiQueryProductState(t "${MSVCREDIST_PRODUCTCODE}")i.r0'` (on a side note, are you sure the statement `${If} ${INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT} = $0` is okay? I was thinking the operator should be `${If} ${INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT} == $0`)

Comment: Although `System::Call 'MSI::MsiGetProductInfo(t "${MSVCREDIST_PRODUCTCODE}", t "ProductName", t"?"r1, *i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})i.r0'` returns `1605`

Comment: Yes I'm sure = is correct, just look at the documentation at the top of logiclib.nsh.

Comment: 1605 is ERROR_UNKNOWN_PRODUCT. You need to replace the MSVCREDIST_PRODUCTCODE define with whatever the GUID for VS2013 x86 redist is.

Comment: I am dealing with `VS2005 x86 redist` so I am using the value: `{A49F249F-0C91-497F-86DF-B2585E8E76B7}`

Comment: Remember that the GUID is not the same if you have SP1 or SP1+updates, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/01/16/mailbag-how-to-detect-the-presence-of-the-vc-8-0-runtime-redistributable-package/

Comment: Please check what I came up with (in the original question - I edited my question to show it). You can also try running that script to confirm my findings. I downloaded the VC2005 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147844/discussion-between-olowookere-emmanuel-and-anders).