# WAMP requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 : VC 11 however that is no longer available on the microsoft website

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, wamp, wamp-protocol

Visual Studio 2012 : VC 11 vcredist_x64/86.exe is no longer available on the Microsoft website though I need it to run WAMP.

This is the link to where the download is supposed to be: 
 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
How can I get these files ? Is there any third party downloads ?

Comment: Links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34209692/366904) seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, WAMPServer support have added an installer for all the MSVC Redist libraries to the Secondary repository of Wampserver files which you can find here. For some reason MS keep messing with the location of these downloads.

[Secondary repository of Wampserver files](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Scroll down to the botton of that page and look for `Microsoft VC++ packages VC2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 zip files`

You can also find the link on the WAMPServer Forum page called [WAMPServer 3 All you need to know](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)