# How to check if Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 is installed on a docker container

Tags: windows, docker, visual-c++

How can I verify that my docker setup to install the **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015-2019** (link: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/9e04d214-5a9d-4515-9960-3d71398d98c3/1e1e62ab57bbb4bf5199e8ce88f040be/vc_redist.x64.exe) has been successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed) as the basis for my answer, however, it seems that when the redistributable is installed on a docker image/container the registry path(s) is/are different.

From Visual Studio, I selected the container from the Containers window/tree, right-clicked and clicked "Open Terminal Window" and pasted the following command:

```
reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Dependencies\ /s /f {f4220b74-9edd-4ded-bc8b-0342c1e164d8}
```

This gave me the following output:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Dependencies\Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14\Dependents\{f4220b74-9edd-4ded-bc8b-0342c1e164d8}
(Default)    REG_SZ    {f4220b74-9edd-4ded-bc8b-0342c1e164d8}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Dependencies\Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Dependencies\VC,redist.x64,amd64,14.21,bundle\Dependents\{f4220b74-9edd-4ded-bc8b-0342c1e164d8}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Dependencies\VC,redist.x64,amd64,14.21,bundle
End of search: 4 match(es) found.
```